# How can I make one module dependent on another in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, module

In ASP.NET, I have noticed that the UrlRoutingModule has a dependency where it requires the UrlAuthorizationModule to also be loaded.

Firstly, do I need to specify in my web.config to load the UrlAuthorizationModule or will ASP.NET resolve this dependency automatically?

Secondly, how can I make my own modules dependant on another, so if the module is not loaded before the pipeline starts executing an exception is thrown indicating to the developer that a required dependency is missing?

Comment: I am not sure if I have found a way or not yet, I will need to test it. If I register the module with the HttpApplication, then loop the modules to find the specific module I've just registered I should be able to call the initialise method. Presumably there is a better way to register dependencies however?

Comment: Actually, this won't work because the classes are internal.